# Update table using certain values from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm faced with a problem where I need to update one table based on values stored in another. However, the second table contains rows which are not relevant to the query. For example:

```
Table1             

id | active     
------------   
 1 |  Yes          
 2 |  Yes          
 3 |  Yes         
 4 |  Yes          

Table2

id | type | value 
--------------------
 1 | date | 2011  
 1 | name | Glen  
 2 | date | 2012  
 2 | name | Mike
```

I want to read the values of type 'date' and skip name, and update table1 in the process.

I've put together the following:

```
UPDATE table1 a, tabel2 b
SET a.active='no'
WHERE a.id = b.id 
AND b.type='date'
AND b.value='2011'
```

This doesn't seem to work well at all.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Title used `using` word twice. removed one.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is the key which joins the tables.

```
UPDATE table1 a, tabel2 b
SET a.active='no'
WHERE a.id = b.id 
AND b.type='date'
AND b.value='2011'
```

Comment: Yeah I am using the ID's already - I forgot to put them above. When I run this though it says 0 rows affected?

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm trying to run it a cron job with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET active = 'no' 
WHERE a.id 
IN ( 
SELECT b.id FROM table2 WHERE type = 'date' AND value = '2011'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with a natural join

```
UPDATE table1 
SET active='no'
WHERE id in
(
select id from table1 natural join table2 
where
type='date'
AND value='2011'
)
```